# JavAPNS Runs Locally but not on Centos

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, apple-push-notifications, centos6, javapns

## Problem

I am experiencing a problem setting up Apple APNS on centos.
I have my Apache tomcat deployed and working fine. Also I am using Javapns to send push messages.

My Push notifications are working fine on windows, (within eclipse and on Apache standalone). but once I deploy the application to the server(centos 6) I get the Error:
**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found**

I am using a p12 certificate that works perfect on Windows as I said. but with no luck on Centos.

## **Environment:**

Apache Tomcat with a Spring 4 deployed webapplication. running on centos 6. with Java 1.7.57.
Using Javapns of course for initiating the Push notifications. And I think it is worthy to mention that my P12 certificate is placed inside the WEB-INF/certs/certificate.p12.

-I do not have a SSL certificate for my webserver.

## My Questions:

- despite the fact that Javapns documentation states that Javapns is designed to work as part of a webapplication or even standalone, Is there any special configuration I have to modify on the server to allow my Service to run?
- What is confusing me is that the same p12 certificate works locally but not on linux?
- Is this something related to security chains on the server? or settings of Apache tomcat to allow such service to run?

I tried almost everything, posting this as I feel really stuck with this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **muenzpraeger** for your suggestion, but it was not the solution.

I could solve this through the great post found on http://cloudfields.net/blog/ios-push-notifications-encryption/

The problem as stated is related to authenticating the certificate to do communication over SSL. I had to command-line the Apple APNS certificate. and things worked like magic.

I am happy though for what you have posted as it lead me to read more about keystores.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When using APNS your server is connecting via SSL to the Apple APNS servers. The message you're receiving means that your used Java environment isn't aware of the issuing certificates - and hence cannot build the trustchain to validate the server certificate.

Check first with the following command `<javabin>/keytool -list -keystore <javahome>/jre/lib/security/cacerts` if you find the Apple certificates in the JVMs keystore.

If you don't find the Apple certs in there you can import them using this command.

```
<javabin>/keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <an_alias> -file   <the_cert_file> -keystore <javahome>/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

You'll get the Apple root and intermediate certificates here: https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/